# Impact force in a fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, free-fall

I'm a climber and I constructed myself an anchor that I fixed to a rock wall. To test it, I hooked to it a 12mm in section steel cable with a length of 2,8m and a concrete block of 30kg to the other tip. I then dropped it from anchor level and it held. I am now wondering what kind of impact force was developed in this test. Can you help me please?

Comment: This doesn't actually look like homework, so I'm removing the homework tag.

Comment: Can you add a diagram please?

Comment: A side note, as I happen to pass here and am a climber myself. I'd like to warn you about your anchor.
Apparently, you repeatedly applied a factor two of fall on the anchor, with a static rope.
By doing so, chances are great that you ruined its mechanical properties.
As for all the gear implied in your test, I wouldn't use it anymore for climbing.

Comment: Hi @Ben Crowell. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thanks for pointing me to that info. After reading it, I still don't think this should have the homework tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the mass reaches its lowest point, the steel wire will have increased in length from $L$ to $L+x$. So equating the strain energy of the wire with the initial gravitational potential energy of the ball:

$$\frac{1}{2}kx^2 = mg(L+x) \approx mgL $$

which rearranges to

$$ x = \sqrt{\frac{2mgL}{k}} $$

Note that

$$ k = \frac{EA}{L} $$

where $E$ is Young's Modulus (about 200 GPa for steel), $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the wire, and $L$ is the length.

The largest force that acts is then

$$ f=kx=\sqrt{2mgEA} $$

I'll let you plug the numbers in.

Comment: Hi, thank you vm for your prompt answer. My numbers add up to 3646. Are those in newtons? It's been a long time since i had physics.

Comment: @kenik If $E$ is in GPa, $L$ in metres, $A$ in metres$^2$, $m$ in kg, and $g=9.8$ ms$^{-2}$, then yes, the final force $kx$ will be in Newtons.

Comment: @kenik: Since you're a climber, you know about static vs dynamic ropes. The whole reason for using dynamic ropes is to reduce the force of impact. This is why the equation in the answer depends on quantities like the Young's modulus. The Young's modulus for a dynamic rope is small, so the impact force is small.

Comment: Btw, the carabiner (which is certified up to 25kn) that was attached to the cable, snapped on the third try. The maillon on the other tip elongated by about 1cm and the anchor held pretty darn good! :)

Comment: I just realised I had an error in my calculations. The result i now have is 3,64N which doesn't make much sense. Anyone got a tip on this?

Comment: @kenik $E$ has to be in $\text{Pa}$, not $\text{GPa}$, to get Newtons.

Comment: Nice to note that the force does not depends on the falling height! This is in principle because a longer rope has a smaller spring constant, so it extends more distributing the impact acceleration on a longer time. It would be a nice high-school-lab experiment to verify this. It should be possible to see that as this formula assumes $L\approx L+x$ this is not completely true.

Comment: @JiK If I use Pa I get 115297,46 which doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: @kenik You should realize that steel is extremely stiff - your block will stop with a 'shock' and thus has an extremely large deceleration. Using newton's F=m*a, it's easy to see that the force must be extremely large. Also note that the actual force may even be larger, since this description assumes quasi-static conditions in the steel wire.

Comment: So, is it realistic to use a value from this formula and if it is, which one is it? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @kenik The 115 kN (note: 8 digits precision is a bit much...) seems fine to me. You may understand now why normal climbing gear is much more elastic... My guess is that about twice the weight will snap the cable - the stress developed in the cable is about 1 GPa, about half of the ultimate tensile strength of high-quality steel.